# Trouble reaching ActiveMQ-Artemis home page with host name and public IP

Tags: azure, ip, ubuntu-18.04, hostname, activemq-artemis

I have two ActiveMQ-Artemis instances with like configuration. They're each running on an Ubuntu VM on Azure. I have host names setup for both -- let's say they're prod01.sys and prod02.sys. Both resolve to the public IP. I can ping both prod01.sys and prod02.sys to confirm. However, only prod01.sys:8443 resolves to the Artemis home page (or prod01.sys:8443/console for the actual console). I can reach BOTH using the private IP.

I'm not sure how to diagnose this further. Here are my bootstrap.xml files for both:

prod01.sys

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">

   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>

   <server configuration="file:/var/lib/broker-HA/etc//broker.xml"/>

   <web bind="https://0.0.0.0:8443"
           path="web"
           keyStorePath="/{path}/keystore.ks"
           keyStorePassword="{secret}">
       <app url="jolokia" war="/opt/jolokia/jolokia-war-1.3.5.war"/>
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>


</broker>
```

prod02.sys

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">

   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>

   <server configuration="file:/var/lib/broker-HA/etc//broker.xml"/>

   <web bind="https://0.0.0.0:8443"
           path="web"
           keyStorePath="/{path}/keystore.ks"
           keyStorePassword="{secret}">
       <app url="jolokia" war="/opt/jolokia/jolokia-war-1.3.5.war"/>
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>


</broker>
```

jolokia-access.xml is identical for both:

```
<restrict>
    <cors>
        <allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>
</restrict>
```

```
<restrict>
    <cors>
        <allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>
</restrict>
```

And here are the ports and ifconfig

prod01.sys

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  1072 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4    30148      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       1667            root    3u  IPv4    34444      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1667            root    4u  IPv6    34446      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
omsagent  30804        omsagent   16u  IPv4 91358169      0t0  TCP *:25324 (LISTEN)
npmd_agen 30854        omsagent    4u  IPv6 91361297      0t0  TCP *:8084 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq   17u  IPv6 76117836      0t0  TCP *:35259 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq   18u  IPv6 76117837      0t0  TCP *:9876 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq   19u  IPv6 76117838      0t0  TCP *:33835 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq   75u  IPv6 76115615      0t0  TCP *:1099 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq   76u  IPv6 76115616      0t0  TCP 10.40.50.17:46775 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq  156u  IPv6 76118634      0t0  TCP *:61616 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq  193u  IPv6 76118635      0t0  TCP *:5500 (LISTEN)
java      88458        activemq  223u  IPv6 76119321      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
rpcbind   95821            root    8u  IPv4 53547139      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
rpcbind   95821            root   11u  IPv6 53547142      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet {private IP}  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast {IP}.255
        inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fe04:1301  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0d:3a:04:13:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 188638370  bytes 46501451447 (46.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 194295204  bytes 46824612750 (46.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8125028  bytes 1891996483 (1.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8125028  bytes 1891996483 (1.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

prod02.sys

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
rpcbind     735            root    8u  IPv4    16921      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
rpcbind     735            root   11u  IPv6    16924      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
systemd-r   998 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4    20488      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       1337            root    3u  IPv4    22325      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1337            root    4u  IPv6    22327      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
java      10408        activemq   17u  IPv6  7185953      0t0  TCP *:45983 (LISTEN)
java      10408        activemq   18u  IPv6  7185954      0t0  TCP *:9876 (LISTEN)
java      10408        activemq   19u  IPv6  7185955      0t0  TCP *:42375 (LISTEN)
java      10408        activemq   75u  IPv6  7185956      0t0  TCP *:1099 (LISTEN)
java      10408        activemq   76u  IPv6  7177821      0t0  TCP 10.40.50.12:43339 (LISTEN)
java      10408        activemq  149u  IPv6  7184849      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
omsagent- 24987        omsagent   16u  IPv4 15027544      0t0  TCP *:25324 (LISTEN)
npmd_agen 25037        omsagent    4u  IPv6 15027058      0t0  TCP *:8084 (LISTEN)
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet {private IP}  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast {private}.255
        inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fee5:2a38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0d:3a:e5:2a:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 33770791  bytes 11475793216 (11.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34878913  bytes 8169417229 (8.1 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2580078  bytes 375020191 (375.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2580078  bytes 375020191 (375.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm not sure what to investigate from here. It's especially confusing for me that prod01.sys brings up the home page, and resolves to the public IP, but the home page does not come up if I use the public IP directly. Where should I look next? I'm not sure if the issue is on Azure, Ubuntu, or Artemis.

Here is a summary of what works and doesn't:

For prod01, these work:

```
https://prod01.sys:8443 
https://{Azure machine name}:8443
https://{private IP}:8443
```

This fail (although it pings)

```
https://{public IP}:8443
```

For prod02, these work:

```
https://{Azure machine name}:8443 
https://{private IP}:8443
```

But these fail (although they ping)

```
https://prod02.sys:8443 
https://{public IP}:8443
```

Comment: Can you connect to sshd using the public IP of prod01? Can you connect to sshd using the public IP/private IP/host name of prod02?

Comment: The only way I can connect to any of these servers with sshd is through the private IP on the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ Artemis configuration looks good to me. I would check the VMs OS firewall rules and the Azure network security group.

You could try to connect to sshd to test your Azure/OS network configuration before to try to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis.